# Layout expand on button press

Tags: java, android, android-layout

What I want to do is have two 'frames'. Left and Right. At application start, the left frame takes up the majority of the space while the right frame is just barely visible.

I want to be able to 'animate' and expand the right frame on button press or on swipe.

Currently, I have the layout set using `weightSum` and `layout_weight`, so my issue is mainly the expanding / animating.

This is similar to how you can pull down the notifications bar in android or in the Facebook app, except from left to right.

Comment: for a sample kind of problem we solved as in this link http://sudarnimalan.blogspot.com/2012/05/android-expand-liner-layout-beyond-its.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do something like the Facebook app, I suggest you look at the [Sliding Drawer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html) class. It allows for both vertical and horizontal configurations.

Comment: Nice. Good call. Didn't know of this feature, let me give it a shot. +1

Comment: Probably what you need, just one more thing, you may need to add an android:orientation="vertical" specifically for you case ...